# How to create tooltip that stay on mouseover in pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip code here. And when I move mouse on this tooltip to click button it disappear. How to make it stay? I don't know how.

```css
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
 <a class="tooltips" href="#">CSS Tooltips
                  <span>Tooltip <button  >Open dialog</button></span></a>
```

Comment: Works for me? https://jsfiddle.net/bLzm8L86/

Comment: @Aer0 He wants the tooltip to stay after he hovers, this is not entirely possible without Javascript. You can add a transition delay but that's hacky. The only way is to use javascript.

Comment: @Win transition delay or very long transition is just transition sparing some extra javascript, not hacky, just unusual value totaly fine for this very purpose  ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus I hope he doesn't go down that route, so I've written an example down below. It gives him a lot of space to extend his tooltips to perform whatever he wants.

Comment: @Win, i did not set an answer about this, i just reacted on the terms *hacky* a bit strong to my own humble opinion ;)

Comment: thx guys for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately adding a permanent state on hover can't be accomplished with pure CSS, you will have to add a small bit or javascript of jQuery. Something like:

```
$('a.tooltips span').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).css({
        "visibility": "visible",
        "opacity": "0.8"
        // more styles go here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This has changed recently and can now be done with pure CSS:

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bop1Lsxa/14/)

```
 .tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #FCF;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hasTooltip:hover .tooltip,
.tooltip:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using pure JavaScript. This is just an example, but you can modify it a lot to match your needs. As mentioned in the comments, you can do it in pure CSS by adding a transition delay on the hover state to something absurd, but using a JS solution will give you a lot of flexibility if you want to add additional functionality.

```js
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip-group');
var closeTooltips = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tooltip-close]');
    
for ( var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++ ) {
  tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function( evt ) {

    // Open tooltip when the user interacts with the
    // element. We will just open the tooltip as
    // an example
    document.querySelector('[data-tooltip-id="' + evt.currentTarget.id + '"]').style.display = 'block';

  });
}

for ( var i = 0; i < closeTooltips.length; i++ ) {
  closeTooltips[i].addEventListener('click', function( evt ) {

    // Event for button within tooltip, this could be
    // replaced for anything such as opening a modal
    // or changing another element
    document.querySelector('[data-tooltip-id="' + evt.currentTarget.dataset.tooltipClose + '"]').style.display = 'none';

  });
}
```

```css
body, html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.f__container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tooltip-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[data-tooltip-id]{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: -60px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="f__container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="js-tooltip" class="tooltip-group">
      JS Tooltip, hover over me :D!
      <div data-tooltip-id="js-tooltip">
        Tooltip!
        <button data-tooltip-close="js-tooltip">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```